# Conditional Formating-Background color set based on dynamic text value

Tags: css

I have an asp page and I am trying to set the background color of a cell based on a dynamic value in that cell. I have created pages already where the values can be edited. This in a simple IN/OUT check-in for our team. For instance, if the value is set to "IN", the the background color is to be green. If the value is "OUT", then set background color is red. If the value is "WAH", then set it to orange. We have 7 Techs that will update this themselves. I have searched for examples, but nothing even close has come up. Besides doing simple web based reports on ASP pages, I know little else. Any help and guidance is appreciated.

Here is my table code. Pretty simple.

```
 <table width="500" border="1" align="center" bordercolor="#000000">
   <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>
         <div align="center"><strong>Mon</strong>
         </div>
     </td>
     <td>
         <div align="center"><strong>Tues</strong>
         </div>
     </td>
     <td>
         <div align="center"><strong>Wed</strong>
         </div>
     </td>
     <td><div align="center"><strong>Thur</strong></div></td>
     <td><div align="center"><strong>Fri</strong></div></td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rather run this check on your server while generating the page contents and assign appropriate CSS classes to the cells so that they can be styled any way you like. CSS does not allow textContent matching.

Comment: Can you provide any examples? This is new to me. I have not done this type of thing before.

Comment: You can generate HTML on the server using the following [pseudo]code: `String className = content; echo "<span class='" . className . "'>" . content . "</span>";` and style the HTML in your CSS: `.IN { color: green; } .OUT: { color: red; } .WAH { color: orange; }`

Comment: Thanks, I have the CSS, but am lost on the rest. Can you send any links for the information on the rest?

Comment: I guess something like [this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/class) will work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to research and learn further. You've put me on the right path. Thanks